# While launching my Rcp application i am getting this error?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I formatted my hard drive and reinstall my os .But after that what ever RCP application i have developed  i am getting error.Can anyone help me.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but when originally compiling, could that have been against a different version of Java than you have now?

Comment: Is your version of Eclipse (and plugins!) the same as before the reinstall?

Comment: Iam using the same eclipse only It is indigo 3.7